# Export cross-domain image from tainted canvas?

Tags: .htaccess, canvas, cross-domain, html2canvas

I really want to use http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ as it goes really a oneliner.
Did anybody managed to do this?

Just please tell me what to put into a .htaccess, and what option needs to be passed to html2canvas.

Comment: If you have access to the server, don't use .htaccess. Instead, configure the server. The server-configuration differs based on your server. Here's a good source of header requirements for various servers: enable-cors.org If you don't have access to server-configuration the .htaccess goes in each directory that you want it to apply to. Here's an example for php: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET" Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type" RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

Comment: Thanks. One thing, may sound dumb. Do I have to serve the images with these headers? Or it is enough to set .htaccess on my client side? (why not post as an answer, btw)

Comment: The .htaccess file needs to be in each directory that you want to expose (and not be in any directories you don't want to expose).  I suggest 1 separate directory containing only images you are willing to expose.  I tend to point people in the right direction rather than answering server configuration questions because there are too many variables in configuration to give a universally complete answer.   Chuckle! Selfishly, configuring a network "remotely" is a pain with many back-forth follow-on questions.  I've endured my share of this pain already during my worklife!